# Como ordenar valores com quantidade de caracteres a mais?

Tags: mysql, sql

boa tarde estou fazendo uma query que busca valores que retornam assim:

```
TEST-1
TEST-2
TEST-3
TEST-4
TEST-5
TEST-10
TEST-11
```

porém quando chega no 10 ele ordena pelo primeiro caractere
por exemplo:

```
TEST-1
TEST-10
TEST-11
TEST-2
TEST-3
...
```

alguém pode me ajuda a query que estou fazendo é essa:

```
SELECT 
    num_pedido,
    nota_fiscal,
    lote_serial,
    produto,
    qtd_disp,
    lote,
    unid_medida,
    pedido,
    status
FROM
    coleta_ordem.clientes_ag 
    order by length(right(pedido,1)), right(pedido,1) asc, length(right(pedido,2)), right(pedido,2);
```

Comment: conseguir fazer estava pegando a coluna errada desculpem o incomodo